# Meson - How to link a shared library to a project?

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, meson-build

I have 2 projects, one of which I want to compile as a shared library and other as my main executable linked the with shared library generated by the other project. Here is the structure of my project,

[image]

I have 3 `meson.build` files one for the `HiveAPI` project which will be compiled as a shared library and one for the `SampleHive` project which is my executable and one main `meson.build` file.

Here is my `meson.build` file for `HiveAPI`,

```
# Source files to be compiled
hive_src = [

  'src/HiveAPI/Core/Application.cpp',
  'src/HiveAPI/Core/Window.cpp',
  'src/HiveAPI/Core/Log.cpp',

  'src/HiveAPI/Input/Input.cpp',

  'src/HiveAPI/GLFW/GLFWLayer.cpp',
  'src/HiveAPI/ImGui/ImGuiLayer.cpp',

  'src/HiveAPI/OpenGL/VertexBuffer.cpp',
  'src/HiveAPI/OpenGL/IndexBuffer.cpp',
  'src/HiveAPI/OpenGL/VertexArray.cpp',
  'src/HiveAPI/OpenGL/Shader.cpp',
  'src/HiveAPI/OpenGL/Renderer.cpp',
  'src/HiveAPI/OpenGL/Texture.cpp',
  'src/HiveAPI/OpenGL/Framebuffer.cpp',

  'src/HiveAPI/Portaudio/Audio.cpp',

  'src/HiveAPI/Taglib/Tags.cpp',

  'vendor/stb_image/stb_image.cpp',

]

taglib_opts = cmake.subproject_options()
taglib_opts.add_cmake_defines({'CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE': 'ON',
                               'CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX': prefix,
                               'CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE': 'Release',
                               'BUILD_SHARED_LIBS': 'ON'})

snd_opts = cmake.subproject_options()

snd_shared = ''

if host_sys == 'windows'
  snd_shared = 'OFF'
else
  snd_shared = 'ON'
endif

snd_opts.add_cmake_defines({'CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE': 'ON',
                            'CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX': prefix,
                            'CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE': 'Release',
                            'BUILD_SHARED_LIBS': snd_shared,
                            'BUILD_PROGRAMS': 'OFF',
                            'BUILD_EXAMPLES': 'OFF',
                            'BUILD_TESTING': 'OFF',
                            'ENABLE_EXTERNAL_LIBS': 'ON',
                            'ENABLE_MPEG': 'ON'})

hive_api_inc = include_directories(['src', 'vendor'])

imgui_subproject = subproject('imgui',
                              default_options: [
                                'default_library=shared',
                                'compile_library=true',])

imgui = imgui_subproject.get_variable('imgui_dep')

glfw = dependency('glfw3')
glew = dependency('glew')

taglib = dependency('taglib', version: '>=1.12', required: false, static: false)

if not taglib.found()
  taglib_subproject = cmake.subproject('taglib', options: taglib_opts)
  taglib = taglib_subproject.dependency('tag')
endif

snd_subproject = cmake.subproject('libsndfile', options: snd_opts)
snd = snd_subproject.dependency('sndfile')

spdlog = dependency('spdlog', version: '>=1.8.5', required: false, static: false)

if not spdlog.found()
  spdlog_subproject = subproject('spdlog',
                                 default_options: [
                                   'default_library=shared',
                                   'compile_library=true',])

  spdlog = spdlog_subproject.get_variable('spdlog_dep')
endif

portaudio = dependency('portaudio-2.0', static: false)

hive_deps = [imgui, glew, glfw, spdlog, portaudio, snd, taglib]

hive_lib = shared_library('hiveapi',
                          sources: hive_src,
                          include_directories : hive_api_inc,
                          install: true,
                          install_rpath: prefix / 'lib')
```

Here is the `meson.build` file for `SampleHive`,

```
# Source files to be compiled
samplehive_src = [

  'src/SampleHive/GUI/Dockspace.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/DirectoryBrowser.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/MainWindow.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/SearchBar.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/SampleViewer.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/WaveformViewer.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/TransportControls.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/TabBar.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/Hives.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/Trash.cpp',

  'src/SampleHive/GUI/Dialogs/ProgressDialog.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/Dialogs/SettingsDialog.cpp',

  'src/SampleHive/Application.cpp',

  'src/SampleHive/Utility/Serializer.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/Utility/Utils.cpp',

]

yaml = dependency('yaml-cpp')

samplehive_inc = include_directories(['../HiveAPI/src', 'src'])

executable('SampleHive',
           sources: samplehive_src,
           include_directories : samplehive_inc,
           link_with: hive_lib,
           dependencies: [yaml],
           install: true,
           install_rpath: prefix / 'lib')
```

And here is the main `meson.build` file,

```
project('SampleHive-Imgui',
        ['c', 'cpp'],
        version : 'v0.1',
        license : 'GPL v3',
        meson_version: '>= 0.56.0',
        default_options : ['warning_level=1',
                           'buildtype=debug',
                           'cpp_std=gnu++17'])

host_sys = host_machine.system()

cc = meson.get_compiler('c')

# Save project information
meson_src_root = meson.current_source_dir()
meson_build_root = meson.current_build_dir()

# Save important directories
prefix = get_option('prefix')
bindir = prefix / get_option('bindir')
libdir = prefix / get_option('libdir')
datadir = prefix / get_option('datadir')

# Import CMake
cmake = import('cmake')

subdir('HiveAPI')
subdir('SampleHive')

include_dirs = include_directories(['HiveAPI/src', 'HiveAPI/vendor', 'SampleHive/src'])
```

but when I try to compile it I get error saying it can't find `imgui` and `spdlog` if I add those to dependencies in the `SampleHive` project then I get undefined references to function defined in the `HiveAPI`.

I want the `HiveAPI` as shared library because I want this to be used by other projects as well either by me or anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood well SampleHive need to link HiveApi as shared lib,        so in SampleHive you need to add the HiveApi dependency:

meson HiveApi:

```
   project(
  'HiveApi')

# Source files to be compiled
        hive_src = [
        
          'src/HiveAPI/Core/Application.cpp',
          'src/HiveAPI/Core/Window.cpp',
          'src/HiveAPI/Core/Log.cpp',
        
          'src/HiveAPI/Input/Input.cpp',
        
          'src/HiveAPI/GLFW/GLFWLayer.cpp',
          'src/HiveAPI/ImGui/ImGuiLayer.cpp',
        
          'src/HiveAPI/OpenGL/VertexBuffer.cpp',
          'src/HiveAPI/OpenGL/IndexBuffer.cpp',
          'src/HiveAPI/OpenGL/VertexArray.cpp',
          'src/HiveAPI/OpenGL/Shader.cpp',
          'src/HiveAPI/OpenGL/Renderer.cpp',
          'src/HiveAPI/OpenGL/Texture.cpp',
          'src/HiveAPI/OpenGL/Framebuffer.cpp',
        
          'src/HiveAPI/Portaudio/Audio.cpp',
        
          'src/HiveAPI/Taglib/Tags.cpp',
        
          'vendor/stb_image/stb_image.cpp',
        
        ]
        
        taglib_opts = cmake.subproject_options()
        taglib_opts.add_cmake_defines({'CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE': 'ON',
                                       'CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX': prefix,
                                       'CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE': 'Release',
                                       'BUILD_SHARED_LIBS': 'ON'})
        
        snd_opts = cmake.subproject_options()
        
        snd_shared = ''
        
        if host_sys == 'windows'
          snd_shared = 'OFF'
        else
          snd_shared = 'ON'
        endif
        
        snd_opts.add_cmake_defines({'CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE': 'ON',
                                    'CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX': prefix,
                                    'CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE': 'Release',
                                    'BUILD_SHARED_LIBS': snd_shared,
                                    'BUILD_PROGRAMS': 'OFF',
                                    'BUILD_EXAMPLES': 'OFF',
                                    'BUILD_TESTING': 'OFF',
                                    'ENABLE_EXTERNAL_LIBS': 'ON',
                                    'ENABLE_MPEG': 'ON'})
        
        hive_api_inc = include_directories(['src', 'vendor'])
        
        imgui_subproject = subproject('imgui',
                                      default_options: [
                                        'default_library=shared',
                                        'compile_library=true',])
        
        imgui = imgui_subproject.get_variable('imgui_dep')
        
        glfw = dependency('glfw3')
        glew = dependency('glew')
        
        taglib = dependency('taglib', version: '>=1.12', required: false, static: false)
        
        if not taglib.found()
          taglib_subproject = cmake.subproject('taglib', options: taglib_opts)
          taglib = taglib_subproject.dependency('tag')
        endif
        
        snd_subproject = cmake.subproject('libsndfile', options: snd_opts)
        snd = snd_subproject.dependency('sndfile')
        
        spdlog = dependency('spdlog', version: '>=1.8.5', required: false, static: false)
        
        if not spdlog.found()
          spdlog_subproject = subproject('spdlog',
                                         default_options: [
                                           'default_library=shared',
                                           'compile_library=true',])
        
          spdlog = spdlog_subproject.get_variable('spdlog_dep')
        endif
        
        portaudio = dependency('portaudio-2.0', static: false)
        
        hive_deps = [imgui, glew, glfw, spdlog, portaudio, snd, taglib]
        
        hive_lib = shared_library(meson.project_name(),
                                  sources: hive_src,
                                  include_directories : hive_api_inc,
                                  install: true,
                                  install_rpath: prefix / 'lib')
            
    #export the include needed
    public_headers = include_directories(['HiveAPI/src'])

    #declare dependency
    project_dep = declare_dependency(
      include_directories: public_headers)
    set_variable(meson.project_name() + '_dep', project_dep)
```

than in the SampleHive meson use the HiveApi dependency:

```
# Source files to be compiled
samplehive_src = [

  'src/SampleHive/GUI/Dockspace.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/DirectoryBrowser.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/MainWindow.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/SearchBar.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/SampleViewer.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/WaveformViewer.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/TransportControls.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/TabBar.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/Hives.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/Trash.cpp',

  'src/SampleHive/GUI/Dialogs/ProgressDialog.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/GUI/Dialogs/SettingsDialog.cpp',

  'src/SampleHive/Application.cpp',

  'src/SampleHive/Utility/Serializer.cpp',
  'src/SampleHive/Utility/Utils.cpp',

]

yaml = dependency('yaml-cpp')

samplehive_inc = include_directories(['src'])

executable('SampleHive',
           sources: samplehive_src,
           include_directories : samplehive_inc,
           link_with: hive_lib,
           dependencies: [yaml,
           dependency('HiveApi', fallback : ['Hive-Api', 'HiveApi_dep']),],
           install: true,
           install_rpath: prefix / 'lib')
```

Comment: This will not work, first I cannot have `project()` in `HiveAPI`'s `meson.build` file because I already have a project definition in the main `meson.build` file. Then the `inlcude_dir` `HiveAPI/src` is not valid because I am already in `HiveAPI` dir and `src` is in the root of this dir. Also you have already declared `hiveapi_dep` in `HiveAPI`'s `meson.build` so there is no need to do `dependency('hiveapi')` in `SampleHive`'s `meson.build` file as they are part of the same project. Your solution might work if `HiveAPI` was a `subproject` which is not the case here.

Comment: Yes my assumption Is to handle HiveApi as a subproject